# Physical interpretation of normalization of wave fuctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, normalization

Does normalization of wave function mean that we are getting our state vector to unit length?  If that's the case what does it mean physically? Also is the underlying vector space finite dimensional? If yes, then what is the dimension and how do I find the basis vectors?

Comment: In QM one could simplify the physical meaning of normalizing a wavefunction to be that it means we are ensuring that there is no more and no less than 100% chance that the particle/system/whatever exists somewhere in the universe (if a function of x), has some momentum (if a function of p), or generally that it is in at least one of the possible states

Answer (score 4):

The physical interpretation of the wavefunction is that it's amplitude squared tells you the probability of finding the particle described by that wavefunction at a certain location:
$$P(\text{particle at $x$}) dx = |\psi(x)|^2 dx$$

The probability to find it in some *interval* is then given by the integral of the amplitude squared over that interval:
$$P(\text{paticle between $x_1$ and $x_2$}) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |\psi(x)|^2 dx$$

Finally, the probability to find the particle *somewhere* has to be exactly one:
$$P(\text{particle is somewhere}) = 1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 dx$$

The same logic applies if we use another basis. For example, if we have a vector describing the spin of the electron, $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ then $|a|^2$ is the probability to find it with spin up, and $|b|^2$ is the probability to find it with spin down. Since both of those probabilities should add up to 1 (after all, if it's not up, it has to be down), we get $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$, which means the vector must have unit length.

Comment: So it does mean we are getting our vector to unit length. Also I found that the underlying vector space is not finite dimensional, it is infinite dimensional, special case of Hilbert space namely space of square integrable functions. Now is the role of normalization in this space to make the finite integral to unity? Also I read that it is possible to find the basis of this vector space. Some hints on how to do that will be helpful.  Finally thank you for the response.

Comment: Square integrable ensures that for all possible wavefunctions $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 dx$ does not give infinity but is finite. Normalization then ensures that this finite value is $1$. A vector space does not have "a" basis. It has many different bases. One such basis for the one dimensional wavefunctions would be the plane wave basis $\psi(x) = 1/\sqrt{L} e^{ikx}$ where $L$ is the system length (one later takes the limit $L \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

When ever the word (normalization) comes then we must necessarely admits that that particle is present in a given interval of space and we are findind its probabilistic location in that interval.  As. We write the the integral =1.   1 means that the particle is necessarily present. And what we have to do? Well... we have to find its probability. So dear dont confuse while analyzing the term (normalization)  .regards. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The wave function tells us about the probability to find the particle in space. So, normalisation of wave function means that the probability to find a particle in a given region is unity. It is the case where the particle is bound by some forces like an electron in atom, the particle in a box with impenetrable walls.
I think this is useful for you to understand it.